# Thunderbird to run even in the background

Tags: thunderbird

I'm wanting to put Thunderbird to run even in the background but don't have that option. I've tried using FireTray but it looks like the version is not compatible. How can I set it up for it to work in the background?
SO: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Thunderbird: 102.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I use `birdtray` from this ppa [https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/apps](https://launchpad.net/%7Elinuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/apps) to minimize Thunderbird to the system tray.  It works 99% of the time, occasionally fails to hide when you click the "-", but the best solution I have found. It shows the number of unread emails on the icon; you can customize what folders it watches and the color of the number for each.

`birdtray` is in the universe repos, but at least in 20.04 it's important to use the ppa version, it works significantly better. (It looks like in 22.04 the universe repo has the version 1.9, so you may not need the ppa in 22.04).